# How to weight a piece of data?

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have a CSV file of weather stations that have a class (class 1 being the most reliable data to class 3 being the worst). I then have distances from the closest weather station to each county. I am attempting to eliminate station-county relationships that might have unreliable data i.e(class 3 station far from a county).

I am struggling to come up with a very general way to do this.

I tried assigned weight to the classes i.e (class 1 = 1, class 2 = .5, class 3 = .1) and then multiplying by distance but that then brings the issue of a close station to a low class give an unreliable read.

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions on this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you only have to decide reliable/unreliable you could for each class define a maximum distance. If the station is farther away, it is unreliable. This of course needs to guess or somehow calculate proper max. distances.

Answer (score 1):

If you want higher weights to have higher significance, and you want longer distance to be associated with a lower weight you should use a decreasing function of the distance as a weight, not an increasing one, as you indicated.

In Physics, a fair share of quantities decreases with the inverse of the squared distance, so I would recommend you use that as a weighting: divide by the distance squared instead of multiplying by the distance.

The decreasing weighting for decreasing class of reliability is just fine.

Of course, the actual scaling and the choice of the weighting function could be investigated further. For example, would: dividing by the cube of the distance, using different values for weighting the classe, etc. be better for your problem? This is something that we cannot easily investigate without further information.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you want to use weights here. Unless you have a robust statistic for reliability that applies to all stations, just assigning arbitrary weightings based on class does not sound reasonable.

How about using a simpler approach? Break the distances from the counties to their weather stations into three categories:

- Near, say < 50 mi / 80 km
- Medium distance, say 50 mi to 100 mi
- Far, say > 100 mi

(Note, these distances are most likely not right for your data set. You’ll have to play around with them to get something appropriate.)

Then, have a matrix of class x distance and discard whichever combinations make sense. It might be that Medium x Class 3 is bad but Far x Class 2 is okay.